# How to make my jQuery Accordion animate smoother 

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I would like my jquery accordion tab animate more smoothly. How do I change the speed?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('.yourAccordion').accordion({ speed: 'slow'});
```

Answer (score 0):

The full documentation can be [found here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) including how to control animation properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.#tab').accordion({speed:"slow"});
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to the smooth action is the `heightStyle`, e.g.

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```