# Changing the behavior of an element in dropdown div (banner) opening smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a dropdown and riseup banner without using jQuery.
I want it to descend and rise smoothly when the triangle will be pressed, as in the picture. The triangle decorated as text for now (but it can be as button too).
The question is how to change the behavior of an element (triangle) after pushing it several times. If I pressed it for the first time, the banner will dropdown and then the triangle must change its direction to up, and 'Show' will change to 'Hide'. If I pressed it again, the banner will rise up and the triangle must change its direction to go down.

Adding a picture for clarity:
[image]

According to [muka.gergely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65482027/18699741) I simplified the example for myself:

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown-wrapper">
        <div class="btn-dropdown">
            Show ▼ 
            <div class="dropdown-content-container">
                <!--Banner-->
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
        const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-dropdown')

        btns.forEach(btn => {
            btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                /* Changing the name of the 'Banner' is not working */
                /* const initialText = "Banner"
                /*if (btn.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(initialText.toLowerCase())) {
                    btn.textContent = 'Hide a Banner';
                } else {
                    btn.textContent = initialText;
                }  
                */
                e.target.classList.toggle('open');
               
            });
        })
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
 
.dropdown-content-container {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: all 1.50s;
}
 
.btn-dropdown.open>.dropdown-content-container {
    height: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: all 1.50s;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PmBrd/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem, the smooth transition, just change or remove the max-height properties and replace them with just the height property.

Max-height is not required here and messes with the css transition.

And the second transition property is not needed as it is already defined.

```
.dropdown-content-container {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: all 1.50s;
}

.btn-dropdown.open>.dropdown-content-container {
  height: 500px;
}
```

For your second problem of changing the name, well you must put the text you want to change into an element so you can access it directly and only change that label and not all of the element (including the container).

So first we need to change the HTML code (I used span but it doesn't matter)

```
<div class="btn-dropdown">
    <span class="dropdown-content-label">Show ▼</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content-container">
        <!--Banner-->
    </div>
</div>
```

and then we need to slightly adjust the JS code to fit this HTML adjustment by getting the label and not the whole dropdown element.

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-dropdown')

btns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        const initialText = "Show ▼"
        const label = btn.querySelector(".dropdown-content-label");
        if (label.textContent.toLowerCase() === initialText.toLowerCase()) {
            label.textContent = 'Hide ▲';
        } else {
            label.textContent = initialText;
        }  
        btn.classList.toggle('open');
    });
})
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Oh, it's working like a magic! Thank you a lot)